# Allow comments on each echoed row of text

Tags: php, mysql

First i echo out each of every "post" that is in the database, then i got another table in my database called "comments" where i want to store every comment made och each "post".

How do i echo the the comment field out so its a individual comment field foreach "post"?

i got it so far that i did echo a comment field out in the while loop, but then its not connected to a specific "post", "post" and "comment" are related in the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT posts.post, user.username,posts.date
        FROM posts, user
        WHERE posts.userid = user.id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<ul>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if(!isset($_POST['sort'])){
    echo '<li>'.$row['username'].': '.$row['post'].$row['date'] .'</li></br>';
  }else{
    $sql = "SELECT posts.post, user.username, posts.date
            FROM posts, user
            WHERE posts.userid = user.id
            ORDER BY posts.date";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo '<li>'.$row['username'].': '.$row['post'].''.row['date'].'</li>'.'<br/>';
```

Comment: You will have to start reading about joins and how a left join will help you here. Read some tutorials like http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php You are facing a very common situation.

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutely must leave the comments in another table, I suggest having that table laid out like this:

```
| id | comment | postid |
|    |         |        |
```

And then you query will look something like:

```
$postid = $post['id']
$commentsquery = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid=$postid";
```

Obviously this requires you to set up an autoincrementing id field for both comments and posts

Comment: i got the database like that but my question is how to get the comment field to know that "this comment show be here" and another comment should be somewhere else?

Comment: Now this is the worst case possible. Never do a query per post id. Use a left join and comments being a separate table is a wise choice. You can't do that in one table properly.

Comment: @Samuel what's wrong with the way I did it? Is it slower than a left join?

Comment: Massively. For querying one post the difference is neglectable but querying 100 posts and fetching their corresponding comments per single query yields in 101 queries whereas a left-join would result in exactly one query. There is no need for any performance comparison as 1:101 should be enough hints :) But feel free to test this, the difference should be massive for any medium scaled query.

Comment: I agree. OP, do the left join thing